# Ember- How to render multiple templates on one page?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

Following http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/ I have

```
<body>   
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2> Welcome to Ember.js</h2> 
    <div class="lists">{{outlet lists}}</div>
    <div class="list">{{outlet list}}</div>  
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="lists">
    <h3> some List Names</h3>    
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="list">
    <h3> a list selected from lists</h3>    
  </script>    
</body>
```

js

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('lists', {path: "/"});
});

App.ListsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render({outlet: 'lists'});
  }
});
App.ListRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  renderTemplate: function(){
    this.render({outlet: 'list'});
  }
});
```

I'd expect to see

### Welcome to Ember.js

#### some List Names

#### a List of selected list name

but that breaks this jsbin: http://jsbin.com/cuyuy/6/edit. I'm still left wondering How to render multiple templates on one page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to give a good answer with this context, but your example will work if you add

```
this.render('list', {
      outlet: 'list'
    });
```

to your renderTemplate hook from ListsRoute. See http://jsbin.com/cuyuy/8/edit

**edit:** Since the code above is not really the ember way, check out this jsbin with nested routes: http://jsbin.com/hutem/1/edit

Comment: 'Ember way' is what I'm after. Thanks. So the ember way is to ...nest outlets and put the nested routes in the callback? What if there was no hierarchy, just multiple sections of a page, each of which you want to keep in its own .hbs file (with its own model and controller)?

Comment: The ember way is not always to use nested routes, but in this case (from what I saw and especially the "lists" and "list" names) it's probably what you want. If you have no hierarchy at all, as far as I know,  you have 2 approaches.
1) Using the controllerFor method in your route: `App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function() {
    this.controllerFor('lists').set('model', App.List.find());
  }
});` and in the template `{{ render "lists" }}` 

2) The renderTemplate you tried to use in your question.